# Adding autocomplete options to auctex C-c C-e?

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

When I'm using auctex with emacs to write LaTeX documents, I would like to be able to add a couple more options to the list of environment types that auctex "recognises" and can autocomplete, namely Theorem, Lemma, Proof, itemize* and a couple of others. Which variable to I need to edit? I have played around in customize-apropos LaTeX and auctex, but I haven't found it.

(lisp code snippet to add to my .emacs would be preferred, I don't quite understand the syntax yete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [AUCTeX manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Adding-Environments.html) that explains this in some detail. For your case and assuming you do not want to write new style files you would add this code to your `~/.emacs` file.

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (LaTeX-add-environments
              '("theorem" LaTeX-env-label)
              '("lemma" LaTeX-env-label)
              '("proof" LaTeX-env-label)
              '("itemize" LaTeX-env-label)
              '("a_couple_of_others" LaTeX-env-label))))
```